# find the p.d.f. first by determining their d.f.’s, and secondly directly..

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

If the r.v. $X$ is distributed as Negative Exponential with parameter $λ$, find the p.d.f. of each one of the r.v.’s $Y, Z$, where $Y = e^X,\, Z = \log{X}$, first by determining their d.f.’s, and secondly directly..

Could any one help me with this question

where $f(x)=λ e ^{− λ x}$ in Negative Exponential

I got $fY(y)=\dfrac{1}{y\ fx(\log{y})}$,  $fZ(z)=e^z fx(e^z)$ in the direct way but I am not sure of my answer

Answer (score 1):

We do it for $Y$, first finding the (cumulative) distribution function of $Y$. Note that $Y$ only takes on values $\ge 1$. For $y\ge 1$, we will find $F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)$. We have
$$\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(e^X\le y)=\Pr(X\le \ln y)=1-e^{-\lambda \ln y}.$$

For the density function, differentiate. We get $\frac{\lambda}{y}e^{-\lambda \ln y}$. If one prefers, one can rewrite this as $\frac{\lambda}{y^{\lambda+1}}$.

Comment: i did it for Z and I got Pr(Z<z)=Pr(log x <z)=Pr( x<e^z)=1-e^(−λe^z) For the density function, differentiate. we get λe^z e^(-λe^z) is this correct/

Comment: Yes, correct. Minor inaccuracies, $\lt$ instad of $\le$. Also should be $\Pr(\log X\le z)=\Pr(X\le e^z)$ (cap $X$). I am being fussy, but have seen too many errors due to notational confusion between random variables and ordinary numerical variables.